# empty recordset. Why?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

In a Odoo 14 shell, I'm doing this

```
env['model_A'].search(['model_B_id', '=', '17' ])
```

I know for sure that there are several records in model_A with the field model_B_id set to 17

I get an empty recordset back

```
model_A()
```

Why ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to search with a string `'17'` instead of an integer `17`?

Comment: If I search with an int I get "Tyep error: 'int' object si not subscriptable" @CZoellner

Comment: @CZoellner why can't I tag people ?

Comment: ok, now with an integer, it works. No message error anymore

Comment: Oh, didn't see the missing brackets. But the answer has everything in it ;) And i don't know why tagging sometimes works and sometimes not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct form of the search is

```
env['model_A'].search([('model_B_id', '=', 17)])
```

Elements to search must be a list of tuples and the many2one relation need an integer